# How to do a "Contains/Like" on an EF5 Integer column vs SQL Server? e.g. Integer version of Name.Contains("Fred")

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have looked though MANY MANY posts on SO and come up with any number of different answers - none of which seem to quite work, or contradict each other based on versions of code etc.

I would prefer to steer clear of the "AsEnumerable()" fix because as I understand it this evaluates all results BEFORE the query is applied...I would like to run the query first so the data in the result is as small as possible.

For info: The tables I am querying can contain +2 million rows.

My requirement:

A "Contains" function on an Integer column of SQL Server (Compact or Standard) through Entity Framework. This would allow a user to enter a number to search on, without having the full number available.  In conjunction with other predicates, this becomes very powerful in reducing the amount of data returned.

e.g.
`f=>f.Id.ToString().Contains("202")<br/>`

This currently fails because "ToString()" cannot be converted to an Entity Store command.

or as a T-SQL equivalent

`cast(Id as varchar(9)) LIKE '%202%'`

Versions: 
EF5
.Net 4.0
SQL Server 2008 Standard OR SQL Compact

Comment: Further info: I could switch to Linq2Sql from Linq2EF, but Linq2EF works with Oracle and supports "Contains" on an Int :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx)

```
f=> SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) f.Id).Contains("202")
```

There is no overload for `int` so you have to cast it to either `double` or `decimal`

Comment: The specified method 'System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])' on the type 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.

Comment: @BlueChippy, are you trying it on SQL Compact ? try it in SQL Server 2008 standard.

Comment: Yes, was testing on compact.

Comment: Well bend me backwards...I would have thought that with removing Linq2SQL for compact that they'd have improved L2E for the same. Note to self: never trust MS to ADD functionality while replacing something!

Answer (score 1):

First you can try use this function:   [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487127.aspx)

```
f=>SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)f.id)).Contains("202")
```

There is no overload for int so you must typecast to double. This function is translated to a corresponding function in the database.

Another solution create an stored procedure and call it from EF:

`objectContext.ExecuteSqlCommand("storedProcedureName", SqlParameters)`

or

```
objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<ResultType>("storedProcedureName", SqlParameters)
```